# Add a property to every array element returned in observable

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular-httpclient

I am making an API call using the HttpClient in Angular. It returns a JSON array of User.

```
users$ = this.httpClient.get<User[]>('api1')
```

I am showing the users (name and email) using the async pipe in the template.

```
<div *ngFor="let user user of users$ | async">
<h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{user.email}}</h2>
</div>
```

Now, for every user, I need to make another (different) API call to get the user's picture URL. How can I efficiently

1. Save the picture URL in the users$
2. Show the picture in the template (img tag)

I don't want to get the images along with the user name and email

Comment: What would be the problem if you read the image url along with the name and email ? I would expect the API to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

As @adrian-fâciu said in the comment, it might be a better idea to add this as a field that's returned with the original response, yet, if you still need to add data, you should augment the users$, either at the service level or at the component.

```
function userWithEmail(user) {
  return getUserEmail(user)
    .map(email => {
      return {...user, email};
    });
}

const usersWithEmail = users$
  .map(users => Observable.forkJoin(...users.map(user => userWithEmail(user));
```

Note the spread (`...`) operator is required because `forkJoin` taks args list and not an array.